# How can a doubly linked list be sorted with the help of a queue and a stack as well?

Tags: data-structures

How can a doubly linked list be sorted using a stack and a queue?

I was asked this question in an interview!

Comment: This sounds like a silly interview question. Was this a follow-up of another question?

Comment: Yes the first question was to explain what a doubly linked list is. And the is was followed by this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Let's try to understand how this can be achieved using a sample Input.

```
Input:- 
34 -> 3 -> 31 -> 98 -> 92 -> 23
   <-   <-    <-    <-    <-
```

Please don't mind my formatting.

So we have a `head*` pointer, that points to the start of the list.

Now my algorithm will look something like:-

```
Step1:- Iterate over this doubly linked list and put all the elements in the queue.
Step2:- We will start iterating over the queue.
Step3:- while stack is not empty do
           (i) Pop an element from input stack call it temp
           (ii) while stack is NOT empty and top of temporary stack is greater than current front queue element,
           (iii) pop from stack and push it to the queue
           (iv) push the current front element in the temporary stack
Step4:- We still have reference to the head pointer and we have our sorted data in the stack, so just iterate over the doubly linked list and update each node element with the stack element.
```

Now, let's go with the algorithm, step by step to understand how this will work.

```
input: [34, 3, 31, 98, 92, 23] in our doubly linked list.

we will fill this to our queue.

queue: [34, 3, 31, 98, 92, 23]
stack: []

Element taken out: 34
queue: [3, 31, 98, 92, 23]
stack: [34]

Element taken out: 3
queue: [31, 98, 92, 23, 34]
stack: [3]

Element taken out: 31
queue: [98, 92, 23, 34]
stack: [3, 31]

Element taken out: 98
queue: [92, 23, 34]
stack: [3, 31, 98]

Element taken out: 92
queue: [23, 34, 98]
stack: [3, 31, 92]

Element taken out: 23
queue: [34, 98, 92, 31]
stack: [3, 23]

Element taken out: 34
queue: [98, 92, 31]
stack: [3, 23, 34]

Element taken out: 98
queue: [92, 31]
stack: [3, 23, 34, 98]

Element taken out: 92
queue: [31, 98]
stack: [3, 23, 34, 92]

Element taken out: 31
queue: [98, 92, 34]
stack: [3, 23, 31]

Element taken out: 98
queue: [92, 34]
stack: [3, 23, 31, 98]

Element taken out: 92
queue: [34, 98]
stack: [3, 23, 31, 92]

Element taken out: 34
queue: [98, 92]
stack: [3, 23, 31, 34]

Element taken out: 98
queue: [92]
stack: [3, 23, 31, 34, 98]

Element taken out: 92
queue: [98]
stack: [3, 23, 31, 34, 92]

Element taken out: 98
queue: []
stack: [3, 23, 31, 34, 92, 98]
```

Now that you have stack in sorted way, you can now iterate over doubly linked list and upate node values without worrying about overwriting previous value of the nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: Worst case time complexity of the above algorithm would be O(n^2) , if we take a list of completely descending order list, then after each iteration only one element will be there in the stack.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wonder what the point of the interview question was. Because you can easily do an insertion sort on a double linked list. That's a whole lot easier than an algorithm that uses queue and stack. In other words, either the interviewer is asking a stupid question about how to complicate a simple sort, or the OP isn't telling us everything.

Comment: I agree with you @JimMischel,like there is no point of asking a question like this, when you have many other approaches to sort a linked list. I don't know what the interviewer was trying to achieve here.

Comment: @SAKSHISITOOT you welcome, can you mark this as answer, it would help future references.